# Service Definition File (.sd)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql

Is there any possibility to make a SD file without using ArcGIS Desktop?

I have to upload my service on a service manager and I am using PostgreSQL as a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can be accomplished with python.

```
import arcpy

mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('C:/Project/counties.mxd') 
service = 'Counties'
sddraft = 'C:/Project/{}.sddraft'.format(service)
sd = 'C:/Project/{}.sd'.format(service)

# create service definition draft
analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES')

# create service definition
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
```

[Related Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000)

Comment: Can I enter this code directly to ArcGIS server?

Comment: I want to create SD file without using ArcGIS software or ArcGIS resources. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure about that one, another question perhaps.